# Combobox selected index changed event not fired in code

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a Windows Forms application and I have a combobox named `cmbCountry`. I am binding this combobox to a list which contains names of countries. Following is the code to populate the combobox.

```
cmbCountry.DataSource = lstcountry;
```

Next I want to set selected item as "**United States of America**". so I added the following code

```
cmbCountry.SelectedItem="United States of America";
```

I want to do some code on selection change event of this combobox.

```
private void cmbCountry_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    \\some code
}
```

This method is suppose to be call when I set the selected item. But it is not getting called. However when I select "**United States of America**" from UI part(Design Part) this event getting called. I want to get called this event when I set the selected item.

Comment: Post how you bind data. what is `lstcountry`

Comment: If you want to fire the event from code, why don't you call the event directly?

Comment: Why not `SelectedIndexChanged`?

Comment: Is this code snippet working `cmbCountry.SelectedItem="United States of America";`, i.e. is the selectedItem changing?

Answer (score 7):

SelectionChangeCommitted fires when the user manipulates via the UI.

> SelectionChangeCommitted is raised only when the user changes the
>   combo box selection. Do not use SelectedIndexChanged or
>   SelectedValueChanged to capture user changes, because those events are
>   also raised when the selection changes programmatically.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted.aspx

Use SelectedIndexChanged or SelectedValueChanged

Comment: Thanks for the answer. now i cleared my concept about selectionchanged event and selectionchangecommitted event of combobox. Once again thanx alot.

Answer (score 0):

Change your event to `SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
private void cmbCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        \\some code
    }
```

And change the event handler (which may be automatically generated):

```
this.cmbCountry.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.lstResults_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Comment: Renaming the function isn't going to do anything. The Handler needs to be changed to handle the proper event.